# In ES5 Javascript, how do I add an item to an array and return the new array immediately, without using concat?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, ecmascript-5

I often find myself in the situation where I want to, in a single (atomic) operation, add an item to an array and return that new array.

```
['a', 'b'].push('c');
```

won't work as it returns the new length.

I know the following code works

```
['a', 'b'].concat(['c']);
```

But I find it ugly code (combining two arrays just to add a single item to the end of the first array).

I can't use `Array.splice()` as it modifies the original array (and returns the removed items). `Array.slice()` does return a shallow copy but you can't add new items.

**ES6**

I'm aware that in `es6` you can use

```
[...['a', 'b'], 'c']
```

But I'm looking for an `es5` solution

**Lodash**

I'm okay in using `lodash`

**Just to be clear**

I'm aware that this can be achieved in several different ways (like the `Array.concat()` method above), but I'm looking for an intuitive simple piece of code, which doesn't "misuses" other operators

Comment: You can do `concat` without `[]` i.e. `['a', 'b'].concat('c')`

Comment: Is that `pop` a typo?

Comment: OP probably meant `push` indeed. Concat with single item seems the best answer, otherwise why not creating a custom `function add(array, item)`

Comment: `concat` is the standard approach here. Of course, we also see people doing things like `return a.push(b), a;`.

Comment: I was not aware of the ability to use concat as `['a', 'b'].concat('c')` which makes its usage a lot more intuitive (not having to add an array around `c`) and basically answers my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I know the following code works `['a', 'b'].concat(['c']);` But I find
>   it ugly code (*combining two arrays* just to add a single item to the
>   end of the first array).

The `concat()` method can be given a single (or multiple) values without the need of encapsulating the value(s) in an array first, for example:

```
['a', 'b'].concat('c');   // instead of .concat(['c']);
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) (my emphasis):

> Arrays and/or **values** to concatenate into a new array.

Besides from that there are limited options without using extension and existing methods.

Example on how to extend the Array (this will return current array though):

```js
Array.prototype.append = function(item) {
  this.push(item);
  return this
};

var a = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(a.append(4))
```

Optionally create a simple function as @torazaburo suggests, which can take array and item as argument:

```
function append(arr, item) {
  arr.push(item);
  return arr;
}
```

or using `concat()`:

```
function append(arr, item) {
  return arr.concat(item)
}
```

Comment: At which point, the method becomes irrelevant as it's basically aliasing `concat`. Well, a much reduced `concat` functionality.

Comment: @torazaburo true. Hm, and not so useful as this would just function as a wrapper.. (rolling back as the last addition is a bit pointless). Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer two methods for `Array.prototype.insert()` which will allow you insert single or multiple elements starting from any index within the array.

**1)** mutates the array it's called upon and returns it

```js
Array.prototype.insert = function(i,...rest){
  this.splice(i,0,...rest)
  return this
}

var a = [3,4,8,9];
console.log(JSON.stringify(a.insert(2,5,6,7)));
```

ES5 compliant version of the above snippet.

```
Array.prototype.insert = function(i){
  this.splice.apply(this,[i,0].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1)));
  return this;
};
```

**2)** Not mutates the array it's called upon and returns a new one

```js
Array.prototype.insert = function(i,...rest){
  return this.slice(0,i).concat(rest,this.slice(i));
}

var a = [3,4,8,9],
    b = a.insert(2,5,6,7);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
console.log(JSON.stringify(b));
```

ES5 compliant version of the above snippet.

```
Array.prototype.insert = function(i){
  return this.slice(0,i).concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1),this.slice(i));
}
```

Comment: He said ES5 solution.

Comment: Yes i noticed and added a subnote. OP has to use apply and arguments combo in the place of spread and rest.